# Export SQL result to Excel

Tags: sql-server

Hello how export SQL result to excel?..
i try  CTRL+SHIFT+C and paste?..but something more specific?

Comment: From where? SQL Server?

Comment: What Database management system are you using?

Comment: `sql` tag by itself doesn't specify the product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have edited your post and tagged it as `SQL Server` ... In your SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) .. in the result window .. You can select all result data (`CRTL + A` will do) and right click .. you can now save it as `*.csv` format

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You can use SQL Yog Software for that it is quite easy to export using sql yog...just install it and connect localhost and then you can export to csv,excel and in html also.